# Is there a Flash onload event?

Tags: javascript, flash, dom-events

Is there any way of detecting an error when a Flash-plugin loads its content?

Basically, what I want to do is to provide some alternate content, in case something goes wrong when the Flash-plugin tries to load it's .swf file.

The .swf file is managed by a CMS type system and hence I want to create some kind of fall back default content, in case something has gone wrong, e.g the .swf file has been deleted.

I know how to detect the flash version etc. but I can't find any resources on this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are embedding with [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), then I think you want to look at the result of your embedding javascript:

```
var so = swfobject.createSWF( ... );
```

Here are some details:
http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/test-embed-success/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such event and you can't detect this with SWFObject either.
It is only possible if you *own* the SWF files.

> NOTE: success is report as true if the minimum Flash player required is available and that the Flash plugin-in  DOM element for the SWF was created. **SWFObject cannot detect if the swf file request has actually loaded or not**.

from: https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api